# Using StringTokenizer to convert a .txt file into a 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tokenize

Text file(twodimension8.txt). The first line is the rows and cols separated by ','

```
4,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
23,55,34,89,41,72
9,27,19,56,33,82
3,65,21,66,85,11
```

My Code so far.
uses TextFileInput class to read from a file

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tokens {
   public static TextFileInput myFile;
   public static StringTokenizer myTokens;
   public static int[][] twodimarr;
   public static String line;
   
 
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      myFile = new TextFileInput("twodimension8.txt");
      line = myFile.readLine();
      System.out.println("The input line is "+line);

      myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

      int row = Integer.parseInt(myTokens.nextToken());
      int col = Integer.parseInt(myTokens.nextToken());

      twodimarr = new int[row][col];

      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
          line = myFile.readLine();
          for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
             myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
             twodimarr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(myTokens.nextToken());
          }
      }

      for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<col;j++)
             System.out.print(twodimarr[i][j]);
          System.out.println();
    }
         
   } //main
}
```

The output:

```
111111   
232323232323
999999     
333333
```

where the problem seems to be is the for loop where it trys to add it into the 2d array. I'm not sure on how I would fix this.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is not recommended. Certainly not needed here. Also avoid 3rd party classes that add little or nothing. `Scanner` would be perfectly simple to use here

Comment: Yeah I heard StringTokenizer is not recommended but it's what my professor told us to use.

Comment: Worrying sign that his teaching materials are out of date by years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual bug is in this block:

```java
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
          line = myFile.readLine();
          for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
             myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
             twodimarr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(myTokens.nextToken());
          }
      }
```

`myTokens` should be reassigned only once per row, not at each individual number. So instead, change that bit to:

```java
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
          line = myFile.readLine();
          myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
          for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
             twodimarr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(myTokens.nextToken());
          }
      }
```

In addition, it's not good practice to store local variables as static class variables. Instead of doing
`public static TextFileInput myFile;` at the beginning of the class definition, do `TextFileInput myFile = new TextFileInput("twodimension8.txt");` at the top of `main`. (same for the other variables).

Comment: ahh I did try putting myTokens in once per row and didn't work but now it does. nice!

Comment: If this helped to resove your question, please mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the concerns I mentioned above:

```
    public static int[][] loadArray(String path) throws IOException {
        int[][] result = null;
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
            s.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]");
            int numRows = s.nextInt();
            int numCols = s.nextInt();
            result = new int[numRows][numCols];
            for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                    result[row][col] = s.nextInt();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```